# Подозреваю накрутку голосов ради знака Академик

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, репутация, знаки

В статистике по знаку [Академик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard) встречается ряд пользователей, которые обычно даже близко не подходили к отметке в 200 репутации за день. Однако, в один прекрасный день, у них случается всплеск популярности. Ровно 200 репутации, полученной исключительно положительными голосами за различные неповторяющиеся вопросы и ответы.

Понимаю, что дело давнее. Но должно же правосудие их настигнуть (или хотя бы проверить).

1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/19883/qweqeqwqeqr-dghd?tab=reputation
2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2564/vinnie?tab=reputation
3. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11139/zelta?tab=reputation (уже исправлено)
4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14313/zarochintsev?tab=reputation
5. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/14645/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE?tab=reputation (исправлено)
6. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1342/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%94%D1%83%D1%80a?tab=reputation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В принципе, проверить можно, но стоит ли? Ну накрутили, ну получили свой значок, не "легенду" же, и не ради чего-то серьезного вроде привилегии правок без peer review. А может и не накрутили, я как-то раз на enSO страдал целый день спамом поправок в SQL-запросах у нубов, набрал свои 235, получил медальку, да и забил, а в обычное время сотня для меня - большой праздник. Хотя если этим пользователям ставил плюсики кто-то один, это будет против правил.

Вообще, посмотрел сейчас пользователей - zarochintsev поймал -75 за "пользователь был удален", zelta -180 за откат голосования (ботом?), Юра -360 за то же, то есть три из 6 поправлены, два автоматически, один постфактум. Но остальные трое - да, похоже, кто-то специально пробегал по сообщениям и голосовал "за", уж слишком подряд эти голоса, в одном случае раза в два больше, чем надо.

Comment: «Преступник должен сидеть в тюрьме» =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin В дополнение к прекрасному ответу, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на даты. Возможно, данные участники "грешили" не настоящими учётными записями. Раньше это проверялось вручную, а как результат, мы что-то упускали из виду, сейчас автоматически.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: да, я сразу обратил внимание на даты. Я понимаю, как это могло произойти, но вопрос–то не об этом. Он о том, что соблюдение правил должно быть обязательным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Прошел по всем упомянутым вами участникам. Постарался найти все их не настоящие учётные записи и объединить в один. В результате, голоса сами себе должны "откатиться". Принял решение не удалять профили, так как наказание должно быть своевременным (администрация ХэшКода допустила ошибку давно, наказывать сейчас не имеет смысла).